# Tried to run a function only when source is committed to a limited path

Tags: gitlab-ci

I read gitlab document on rules(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) but I'm not sure I understood properly.

---

Goal - Run a function only when committed to a limited path.

---

My first script didn't work,

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - some commands
  rules:
    - changes:
      - limited/path/*
    - when: always

stages:
  - test
```

Below script worked as intended.

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - some commands
  only:
    changes:
      - limited/path/*

stages:
  - test
```

Is this because I left `- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` under `rules:`?
Should I remove `when: always` also? Can I assume that `only` is a sub-concept of `rules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule definition should be something like this:

```
rules:
    - changes:
      path:
       - limited/path/*
      when: always
    - when: never
```

From your original syntax the job run on change and always, this definition makes run always on change on the path and never for all other cases (you can see the single rule `- when: never` as the default option for the rules).